# Azure Dev Ops: Is there a way to hide comments in the discussion field from one group/team from another?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

Is there a way to hide comments in the discussion field from one group/team from another?

E.g. Group 1 makes a comment on the work item but Group 2 cannot see the comment.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no access control for individual fields within work items.